# Fontello Icon not showing up React Native Ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-vector-icons, fontello

I'm trying to implement custom icons with Fontello on React Native with IOS but running into the same problem. I followed all the required steps from documentation by installing vector-icons and then linking them. Next I placed the .ttf file in my /assets/fonts folder and linked those as well. I checked that the .ttf was placed in resources in the ios folder as well as the build phases and info.plist. However, when I run it, the font shows up as question mark inside a box which responds to size and color. What should I be doing? I tried restarting, relinking, and deleteing and reinstalling the app among other solutions.

Here is the code for the icon:

```
import { createIconSetFromFontello } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import fontelloConfig from '../config.json';
const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig);

...

 render(){
    StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true);
    return (
      <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
        <Icon name="icon_x" size={80} color="#bf1313" />
...
```

An image of what the output looks like:
[image: f]

Comment: Could you also add the code that adds the icon?

Comment: Just added the code!

Comment: It could be that the name prop you pass, `icon_x`, is not correct. If that is the case it will probably give you a warning in your bundler.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I double checked the name when I downloaded it and looked through the warnings. If I don't pass in the name icon_x, the simulator correctly warns and asks if I'm looking for icon_x and has the ? without the box.

Comment: Have you added the location of your /assets/fonts folder to your package.json file?

Comment: Yes, I've added this line of code at the first level:   "rnpm": { "assets": [ "assets/fonts" ] },

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?